# FPDF error: Can't open image file: http://chart.apis.google.com/char

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using googlechartphplib to generate my charts. They are generated as images. Heres an example of one image - [Click Here](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=pc&chs=200x200&chtt=Svetain%C4%97%20veik%C4%97%3F&chd=t%3A50.00%2C40.00&chco=25C114%2CC11425&chl=50%7C40&chdl=Taip%7CNe&chdlp=bs). I store this url as `$pie_chart1_url`.

I am trying to make a pdf file, and i want to put this image inside this pdf. I am using fpdf class for this. I dont understand why am i having this problem:

```
$pdf->Image($pie_chart1_url, 0, 40, 0, 0, 'png');
```

Getting this error:

> FPDF error: Can't open image file: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart....` error.

If i write it manually:

```
$pdf->Image('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=pc&chs=200x200&chtt=Svetain%C4%97+veik%C4%97%3F&chd=t%3A50.00%2C40.00&chco=25C114%2CC11425&chl=50%7C40&chdl=Taip%7CNe&chdlp=bs', 0, 40, 0, 0, 'png');
```

It works without any errors..

Comment: Well its almost certainly that $pie_chart1_url doesnt contain the exact string you think it does. The Image() function jsut receives the string, it doesnt know how it got the string. So check that the code is storing the exact full (and proppelly encoded) URL.

Comment: I did a var_dump and its exactly the same url, how else can i check it?

Comment: Maybe its not encoded correctly. When you var_dump it, the browser is receiving it and fixing the encoding. So when you copy it back into a string, its already been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You must have the directive [`allow_url_open`](http://php.net/manual/fr/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) activated